# Creating dynamic table using Object labels and values in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a sample object with static `table` manually I created. But how can I create the same table using jQuery by dynamic? How to write the logic for this?
I don't have any idea about this.

```js
var data = {
  parent1: "p1c data",
  parent2: {
    p2_child1: "p2c data1",
    p2_child1: "p2c data2"
  },
  parent3: {
    p2_child1: "p3c data1",
    p2_child2: "p3c data2",
    p2_child3: {
      p2_c2_1: "p2_c21 data1",
      p2_c2_2: "p2_c21 data2"
    }
  }
}
```

```css
table{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-bottom:0;
}

td,th{
  border-right:1px solid green;
  border-bottom:1px solid green;
}
td:last-child,th:last-child{
  border-right:0;
}

.center{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Sample static table to be generated by dynamic </h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>parent1</th>
    <th colspan="2">parent2</th>
    <th colspan="4">parent3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data1</td>
    <td>p2c data1</td>
    <td>p2c data2</td>
    <td>p3c data1</td>
    <td>p3c data2</td>
    <td colspan="2" class="center">p2_child3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5"></td>
    <td>p2_c21 data1</td>
    <td>p2_c21 data2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How do you generate the json object?

Comment: either by getting it from back-end nor by manual.

Comment: Is this `<td>data1</td>` meant to be in your html?

Comment: As a simple thing, I would like to keep the `labels` in the `th` and the datas in the `td` by it's tree structure. if possible even you can create your own data structure with dynamic table and post for us

Comment: Have you tried *anything*? Do you know how to code in javascript? Do you know how to use [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)? Please provide more context.... your question doesn't give us a starting point to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would build this JSON, so that all of the elements have `name` and `content` keys in this example. You can call them whatever you want. And then if the element would have children then it would have `children` key with exactly the same structure as their parent inside. For building the table from that the easiest would be to use recursion. The example below returns a table cell with the element's `content` if there are no children or it returns the element's `name` following by it's children if there are children. It looks similiar to Your example, so I hope this is helpful [image]

Here's the code running on modified data from Your example:

Javascript's main.js:

```
var data = [
  {
    "name": "parent1name",
    "content": "parent1data",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "child1name",
        "content": "parent1child1data"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "parent2name",
    "content": "parent2data",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "child1name",
        "content": "parent2child1data"
      },
      {
        "name": "child2name",
        "content": "parent2child2data"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "parent3name",
    "content": "parent3data",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "child1name",
        "content": "parent3child1data"
      },
      {
        "name": "child2name",
        "content": "parent3child2data"
      },
      {
        "name": "child3name",
        "content": "parent3child3data",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "child1name",
            "content": "parent3child3grandchild1data"
          },
          {
            "name": "child2name",
            "content": "parent3child3grandchild2data"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

var root = document.getElementById('root');
var table = document.createElement('table');

var tableCells = table.insertRow();

var returnAllContent = function(item, currentRow) {
  item.map(function(element) {
    var td = currentRow.insertCell();
    if (!element.children) {
      td.innerHTML = element.content;
    }
    else {
      var insideTable = document.createElement('table');
      var tr1 = insideTable.insertRow();
      var td1 = tr1.insertCell();
      td1.innerHTML = element.name;
      tr2 = insideTable.insertRow();
      returnAllContent(element.children, tr2);
      td.appendChild(insideTable);
    }
  });
}

returnAllContent(data, tableCells);

root.appendChild(table);
```

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Building table</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#root {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
tbody {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
tr {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
td {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}
td table {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```